# Woocommerce- Product attribute type - date

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Product attribute type only has a type of text. Any idea how to change it to date? Should I use any plugin, or can directly change the database field type?

Comment: Could you be more explicit, please… Why do you need a product attribute type date? what do you want to do?

Comment: Product attribute type has two... select and text..

Comment: For example, a product has expiry date that users want to filter by.

Comment: Reigel, yes. Is it possible to add another? Date type.

Comment: why you dont use a custom field instead of a product attribute? You have a free plugin that can handle (may be) what you want to do: [WC Fields Factory](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/) and if you want, you can read this article related to [WooCommerce Custom Product Fields](http://gerhardpotgieter.com/2013/09/17/woocommerce-custom-product-fields/)

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec. Could you post your comment as an answer?